# Android in-app billing example, wrong source files?

Tags: android, billing

I downloaded the Android in-app billing example and imported it into Eclipse. After import I see some strange errors.

There is a source file AccelerometerPlay and the string resources in the Dungeons.java file are not existing.

It seems that the download got the wrong resources. Has anybody seen this and knows how to get the right code?

Of course I can put in my own strings to get rid of the error markers, but I cannot say if something else is missing. So I'd rather have a correct version of the code.

Comment: Have you got the correct imports? ctrl + shift + o in your class. As an alternative you could try this http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/ Billing Tut

Comment: tried it again and again now it loads the right sources, no clue why I had the wrong sources there.

Answer (score 0):

How can I take over this question? It is not resolved for me and I can not up-vote it or comment on it stating this still persists for me. Duplicating the question can't be the solution neither.

More details:
The Dungeons example is not in "Extras/Google Market Billing Package" as shown in the screenshot in their tutorial but in "Extras/Google Play Billing Library"
The version of this is "revision 2".

After removing it via the Android SDK Manager various times and adding it again to re-create the project from source within Eclipse, I now did check the "create Activity .Dungeon" checkbox in the last step and think that did the trick. I'm not eager to verify this assumption ending up without a broken project again though.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse and Intellij, if you create a new app over those existing sources (and presumably have it create a default activty like "MyActivity") it will overwrite some of the billing files namely the main layout and the strings file.